# Disable generation of crash logs from device

Tags: ios

I want to disable the app crash log. Is it possible to disable the crash log from device.If it is possible Appstore is allowing this?

Comment: May I ask: why?

Comment: @luk2302 currently we are working on the bank project. So their requirement like this

Comment: That does not make sense, sounds like security by obscurity. You know I can decompile the application and inspect it, etc., a crash log will contain far less information.

Answer (score 2):

Crash reports are created and written by the operation system. There is no public API available to prohibit the operation system from doing so. So no, it is not possible.